Stopping Email Notification for New Community Users Created via SAML JIT Handler
I’m setting up SSO with the SAMLJitHandler and creating community users automatically through the JIT process. I’ve already unchecked the Send welcome email option, but users are still getting an email. I think it's coming from the Generate new password and notify user immediately setting.
Has anyone run into this before? How do I stop this email from being sent when creating users through the JIT handler?
JIT Handler Class:
global class JitHandler implements Auth.SAMLJitHandler {
    private class JitException extends Exception{}
    private static final string PROFILE_NAME ='Profile 1';
    global User createUser(Id samlSsoProviderId, Id communityId, Id portalId,
        String federationIdentifier, Map<String, String> attributes, String assertion) {
            User newUser = new User();
            try{
                validateAttributes(attributes,newUser,federationIdentifier);
            }
            catch(exception ex){
            }
            return newUser;
    }

    private void validateAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes, User newUser, String federationIdentifier){
        newUser.FederationIdentifier = federationIdentifier; 
        
        if(attributes.containsKey('Email') && attributes.get('Email') != null ){
            newUser.Email = attributes.get('Email');
            newUser.Username = newUser.Email+'.clouderacustomer';
        }else{
            throw new JitException('Email Attribute is missing in SAML');
        }

        if(attributes.containsKey('FirstName')  && attributes.get('FirstName') != null){
            newUser.FirstName  = attributes.get('FirstName');
        }else{
            throw new JitException('FirstName Attribute is missing in SAML');
        }

        if(attributes.containsKey('LastName')  && attributes.get('LastName') != null){
            newUser.LastName  = attributes.get('LastName');
        }else{
            throw new JitException('LastName Attribute is missing in SAML');
        }
    }
}


Unchecking the Send welcome email option is an asynchronous operation, it takes time to execute. Other than that, turn on your debug logs and see what's up.
